# Summing the child nodes in an XML using oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have XML in the following format

```
<Receive
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Date>20171106</Date>
    <ReceiptDetails>
        <ReceiptDetail>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        </ReceiptDetail>
        <ReceiptDetail>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        </ReceiptDetail>
        <ReceiptDetail>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </ReceiptDetail>
        <ReceiptDetail>
            <Quantity>4</Quantity>
        </ReceiptDetail>
    </ReceiptDetails>
</Receive>
```

Now I want a query Oracle SQL query which returns me the sum of the Quantities Node.

I wrote a query which is concatenating the values.

```
SELECT 
 XMLTYPE(t.REQ_MSG).EXTRACT('//Receive/ReceiptDetails/ReceiptDetail/Quantity/text()').getStringVal()
FROM 
   TABLE_NAME t;
```

This Gives me 3214 which is the Concatenated value but I want 10 which is the Sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider parsing XML node into a column using `XMLTABLE` and then aggregate in outer query.

```sql
SELECT  SUM(e.Quantity) AS SumQuantity

FROM  XMLTABLE('/Receive/ReceiptDetails/ReceiptDetail' 
      PASSING XMLTYPE('<Receive xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                            <Date>20171106</Date>
                            <ReceiptDetails>
                                <ReceiptDetail>
                                    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                                </ReceiptDetail>
                                <ReceiptDetail>
                                    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                                </ReceiptDetail>
                                <ReceiptDetail>
                                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                                </ReceiptDetail>
                                <ReceiptDetail>
                                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                                </ReceiptDetail>
                            </ReceiptDetails>
                        </Receive>')
       COLUMNS
        Quantity NUMBER PATH 'Quantity') as e
```

And for the XML column in a table

```sql
SELECT  SUM(e.Quantity) AS SumQuantity

FROM  MY_TABLE,
      XMLTABLE('/Receive/ReceiptDetails/ReceiptDetail' 
      PASSING XMLTYPE(MY_TABLE.MY_XML_COLUMN)

      COLUMNS
        Quantity NUMBER PATH 'Quantity') as e
```

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/MSJS72695)

Comment: Thanks for that. I searched for a solution could not find it at all! Where did you learn this from? If you could give me an article or something would be great!

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I could help. A simple Google/Bing search on *Oracle xmltable* can help you find tutorials, docs, even SO posts. If you didn't know the term simply search on how to query an XML in Oracle. Many examples out there.